# How can I get a list of all deterministic functions made by a user in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want a list of all determinstic functions created by the current user on a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select owner, object_name, object_type, deterministic 
from user_procedures 
where object_type='FUNCTION' and deterministic='YES'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that functions are kept in user_procedures